# Ghetto Tubeless w/ Gorilla Tape on a BMX Bike or Dirt Jumper - Good Idea?

Tags: rims, bmx, tubeless

Why or why wouldn't you go tubeless on a 20" BMX or DJ bike?

Got *a lot* of pinch flats recently and was look for a better solution than having to buy a tube every day/

I was considering doing the gorilla tape method on my 20" single wall BMX... is this a bad idea?

From my research, I've found:

**Tubeless Cons**

- Sidewall takes a beating in BMX / DJ causing the tires to burp (more dangerous, could cause crash)
- Sometimes you want higher tire pressure (BMX street riding) and tubeless is not good for high pressures

**Tubeless Pros**

- Lighter (by a little)
- Easier flat maintenance
- Better against thorns than a tube
- Is able to run lower tire pressure for more grip
- Cheaper in the long run (tubes are ~$10 a pop)

I mostly dirt jump with my BMX, so I see more pros than cons. Any experience or thoughts?

Comment: Not easier flat maintenance.  You go flat you walk home.  A field pump does not have the volume to seat a tubeless.

Comment: @Paparazzi Most of the time BMXing, I have a car compressor, (the kind that plugs into the cigarette lighter) available because I drove to the bike park. Or I could throw a C02 cartridge in my B-Pack?

Comment: One CO2 cart negates any negligee price savings you might have had. And many tubeless tires just won’t set with CO2.

Comment: @RoboKaren Good point :\

Comment: And if your car compressor is one of those tiny 12v emergency compressors, it also won’t have the volume and capacity of air to set a tubeless tire.

Comment: "Could cause crash" seems like it overwhelms all the pros, but maybe I'm just more risk-averse.

Comment: @AdamRice I wonder if it really would cause a crash though? I've ridden DH bikes that take 5X the beating of a BMX and are tubeless. Never caused a crash

Comment: @KolobCanyon You listed crash as a con.  Were the DH you rode ghetto?  You clearly want to go tubeless. Just do it.  You don't need our permission.

Comment: @Paparazzi The one I rode wasn't ghetto tubeless. My friend rides a YT Capra (Enduro Bike) that is ghetto tubeless and he has had no issues.

Comment: On mountain bikes, the big overriding reason to ride tubeless is the ability to use very low pressures and not worry about pinch flatting. That is neither here nor there in dirt jump or street BMX. You need moderate to high pressures to keep from destroying your rims.

Comment: Search around more - tubes are half to a third of that price.

Comment: @Criggie I guess that's what I get for going to my LBS and buying a tube

Comment: @KolobCanyon a LBS has what you want, then and there, and you can discuss what you want while picking their brains.  Buying online you have to know exactly what you need, sight unseen, and wait a day to a month for it to arrive.  They serve slightly different requirements.  Depends how prepared you are, and how far ahead you need the items, and how accurately you know what you need.  I'd be happy to pay 5x as much to the LBS I'm walking past while broken down.

Answer (score 3):

Your pros list for tubeless is highly debatable.

Tubeless are less likely to puncture and more likely to self seal if they do puncture, so you have to fix less often, but.... Fixing a tubeless puncture that did not self seal is a workshop job, not a field job. MTBers running tubeless carry spare tubes so they can get home if they puncture.

Weight - much less a concern for DJ and BMX bikes. In reality, most riders could afford to loose 100 times more weight than the difference tubeless makes.

Cheaper in the long right - very doubtful. Tubeless require a slime top up every 3 - 6 months.  Tubes are a one off lifetime cost.

As is you cons list.
Maintenance - 3-6 monthly slime topup vs an occasional squirt of air into a tube.

Cost - slime is not cheap.

IMHO tubeless for a DJ or street BMX makes little sense as the single big advantage - running lower pressures to get more grip cannot be utilized.

Comment: Could you explain why running lower pressures cannot be utilized? To protect the rims?

Comment: Yes. MTBers run lower pressures to get better grip. BMX and DJ don't tend to need to run as low pressure.  The decision to go tubeless would be worth it if you are suffering pinch flats at desired pressures though.

Comment: @KolobCanyon Can you explain how running at a lower pressure protects the rims?

Comment: The only reason I was interested in tubeless was because I was losing grip on dirt badly. That's probably the street tires fault tho - I have a Maxxis High Roller coming in the mail

Comment: @Paparazzi I didn't say it protected the rims.On MTB it doesn't hurt them tho (where you go over huge rocks all day) versus BMX which is on smooth trails and street... I'm not doubting what you're saying, just learning here and getting my facts straight. I'm glad I asked because I'm not going to waste the time converting my BMX to tubeless now. That +1 was me and I will accept this answer if no one else wants to chime in

Comment: Doesn't hurt them is a reason to run low pressure?  Why do you need low pressure?

Comment: @Paparazzi Idk, I thought it might help grip on dirt and reduce the number of flats. I got 3 flats in 3 days and that's what brought me here

Comment: This is important information that should be in the question. Were the flats 'snake bite' (caused by from low pressure), or punctures?

Comment: @KolobCanyon You don't even mention pinch flats in the pros.  I get you are probably young and new to the site but answers are only as good as the question.

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: @Paparazzi My question was clear. I was asking if tubeless was good on a bmx. This is aside from the fact that I got lots of flats lately.

Answer (score 2):

Better off using tubes and making sure they line the rim properly / are seated properly and you have inflated them enough. For SS / DJ you need air. Like 60PSI or more not uncommon to avoid pinch flats. Also it helps to learn how to not smash curbs and things will full velocity.

Answer (score 2):

I've run tubeless "ghetto" style before. Meaning on rims and tires not specifically designed for tubeless. It's not that hard, other than getting the beat to seat, but that's a pain anywhere. I used STAN's rim strips that have the valves built in, and a ring of gorilla tape. I would always have wet beads, but not enough to drip out. It will function.

That said, like others have said, this isn't really solving the problem you want. You're supposed to run high pressure for BMX and DJ stuff. If you are having traction issues, maybe try better tires? I don't know what's available for BMX size, but on a 26" DJ you could try pretty much anything. I use Maxxis Holy Rollers on my DJ (again, a 26") and I get very good dirt traction. One place I have had traction issues is in indoor skate parks, particularly when they haven't cleaned the ramps recently. But lower pressure is exactly what you don't need in situations like that.

One think you could try is putting STANs sealant inside your regular tube. It should sell seal punctures. You would build up a lot of sealant between your tube and tire over time. I don't know what effect this would have on anything.

But it sounds like the best bet here is better tires, "double thick 'DH' tubes, if they have such a thing for 20", and high tire pressure.

If the harshness of high pressure is what's making you want to drop the pressure, gif a 26" mtb-type DJ bike for a spin.

Comment: Agree, gorilla tape is your friend. You can line your rims with it, no downside really.